# Problema com PUT axios Laravel

Tags: laravel, axios

Estou utilizando o Laravel 5.6, rotas e controller com resource e no scritpt Post o código funciona normalmente, porém com o PUT ele sempre dá erro.

Segue o código funcionando do POST

```
        const fileInput = document.querySelector( '#trv_arquivo' );
        const formData = new FormData();
        if (document.querySelector('#trv_arquivo').value ){
            formData.set( 'trv_arquivo', fileInput.files[0] );
        }            
        formData.set( 'placa', document.querySelector('#placa').value );
        formData.set( 'marca_id', document.querySelector('#marca_id').value );
        formData.set( 'modelo_id', document.querySelector('#modelo_id').value );
        formData.set( 'cor_id', document.querySelector('#cor_id').value );
        formData.set( 'situacao_id', document.querySelector('#situacao_id').value );
        formData.set( 'pendencia_id', document.querySelector('#pendencia_id').value );
        formData.set( 'data_entrada', document.querySelector('#data_entrada').value );
        formData.set( 'data_saida', document.querySelector('#data_saida').value );
        formData.set( 'plaqueta', document.querySelector('#plaqueta').value );
        formData.set( 'trv', document.querySelector('#trv').value );
        formData.set( 'chave', document.querySelector('#chave').value );


        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/automoveis',
            data: formData,
            config: { headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }}
        })
```

No put eu mudo o method para 'put', porém sempre da seguinte erro no console:

```
PUT http://projeto/automoveis 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $input = $request->all();

    request()->validate([
        'placa'         => 'required|max:10',
        'marca_id'      => 'required|max:3',
        'modelo_id'     => 'required|max:3',
        'cor_id'        => 'required|max:3',
        'situacao_id'   => 'required|max:3',
        'pendencia_id'  => 'required|max:3',
        'data_entrada'  => 'required|max:10',
        'data_saida'    => 'max:10',
        'plaqueta'      => 'max:11',
        'trv'           => 'max:11',
        'trv_arquivo'   => 'max:1024',
        'chave'         => 'max:3',
    ]);


    if (isset($input['trv_arquivo'])){

        request()->validate([
            'trv'           => 'required|max:11',
            ]);

        $input['trv_arquivo'] = "transito/automoveis/TRV-".$input['trv'];

        $trv_arquivo = $request->file('trv_arquivo');

        $trv_nome = "TRV-".$input['trv'].".pdf";        

        $path = $trv_arquivo->storeAs('transito/automoveis/', $trv_nome);
    }    



    $automovel = TransitoAutomovel::create($input);

    \Session::flash('success_message',trans('global.flash.fields.adicionar')); //<--FLASH MESSAGE

    return ['redirect' => route('automoveis.index')];

}
```

UPDATE

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $input = $request->all();

        request()->validate([
            'placa'         => 'required|max:10',
            'marca_id'      => 'required|max:3',
            'modelo_id'     => 'required|max:3',
            'cor_id'        => 'required|max:3',
            'situacao_id'   => 'required|max:3',
            'pendencia_id'  => 'required|max:3',
            'data_entrada'  => 'required|max:10',
            'data_saida'    => 'max:10',
            'plaqueta'      => 'max:11',
            'trv'           => 'max:11',
            'trv_arquivo'   => 'max:1024',
            'chave'         => 'max:3',
        ]);

        if (isset($input['trv_arquivo'])){

            request()->validate([
                'trv'           => 'required|max:11',
                ]);

            $input['trv_arquivo'] = "transito/automoveis/TRV-".$input['trv'];

            $trv_arquivo = $request->file('trv_arquivo');

            $trv_nome = "TRV-".$input['trv'].".pdf";        

            $path = $trv_arquivo->storeAs('transito/automoveis/', $trv_nome);
        }   

        $automovel = TransitoAutomovel::find($id);

        $automovel->update($input);

        \Session::flash('info_message',trans('global.flash.fields.editar')); // FLASH MESSAGE

        return ['redirect' => route('automoveis.index')];
    }
```

Comment: Apenas informa que o método `PUT` não é permitido, você definiu essa rota como `PUT` usando `Route::put('automoveis')` ?

Comment: Route::resource('automoveis','Transito\TransitoAutomovelController');

Answer (score 1):

Quando você usa `Route::resource('automoveis')` para gerar suas rotas, ele gera as seguintes rotas:

```
Método        Caminho                       Ação    Route Name
GET           /automoveis                   index   automoveis.index 
GET           /automoveis/create            create  automoveis.create
POST          /automoveis                   store   automoveis.store
GET           /automoveis/{automovel}       show    automoveis.show
GET           /automoveis/{automovel}/edit  edit    automoveis.edit
PUT|PATCH     /automoveis/{automovel}       update  automoveis.update
DELETE        /automoveis/{automovel}       destroy automoveis.destroy
```

Logo, a rota `POST` funciona para cadastrar um `Automovel` mas se voce quer atualizar as informações do `Automovel`, então você precisa acessar a rota `/automoveis/{automovel}`.

Quando quiser saber as rotas do seu Laravel e quais métodos ela permite, use `php artisan route:list` e o próprio Laravel gerará uma lista como a tabela que eu mostrei.

Comment: Olhei aqui, na verdade ficou a rota /automoveis/{automovei} (redução do inglês). Porém mesmo colocando essa url /automoveis/{automovei} no put ele gera erro console:
 PUT http://projeto/automoveis/%7Bautomovei%7D 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

Comment: A url `/automoveis/{automovei}` é um `pattern`, você precisa substituir `{automovei}` pelo `id` do automóvel, ficando `/automoveis/5` por exemplo.

Comment: O problema é justamente esse, posso até passar a ID direta no put que ele da o mesmo erro

Comment: Comente aqui qual é exatamente o erro mostrado. Lembrando que, o `id` do automóvel precisa ser válido se não ele lança um erro que não foi encontrado.

Comment: Ele não processa os inputs, mesmo passando a url certa

Comment: Atualiza a pergunta com o código do Controller, do Request caso tenha para que eu possa te ajudar melhor. Se estiver lançando algum erro, coloque também.

Comment: Coloquei os métodos do controller na pergunta.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83461/discussion-between-vinicius-lourenco-and-rafael-meirim).